# Why can't I assign a struct variable an element of an array of the same type of structs?

Tags: arrays, c, variables, struct

I tried to assign a struct variable values from an array of the same type of structs using = operator, like below:

```
struct s {
    int dummy;
    char somechar[8];
} array_of_s[10];

void f(void)
{
    struct s a = array_of_s[0];  // this line gives me error message
}

int main(void)
{
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting an error message and it says:

```
a value of type "struct s" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "struct s"C/C++(144)
```

But if I hand over array as an argument like below it works like a charm:

```
struct s {
    int dummy;
    char somechar[8];
} array_of_s[10];

void f(struct s array_as_parameter[])
{
    struct s a = array_as_parameter[0];
}

int main(void)
{
    f(array_of_s);
    return 0;
}
```

Why is the first code illegal? Shouldn't I be able to access to external array variable and assign it?

Comment: Try using an assignment instead of initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get it.

`gcc -Wall -Wextra -o main main.c` compiles just fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct s {
    int dummy;
    char somechar[8];
} array_of_s[10] = {{123, "abc"}};

void f(void)
{
    struct s a = array_of_s[0];
    printf("%d, %s\n", a.dummy, a.somechar);
}

int main(void)
{
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
123, abc
```

On the other hand, VSCode shows me that error message too.

It is a bug, have a look at this: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/3212

Comment: @Clifford I have to apologize, i missunderstood your comment. You were right from the begin. I have no clue, what i have read, my answer to your comment was not (that) fine.

Comment: No need.  I assume by "_I don't get it_" you mean you don't get the error, rather then meaning "_I don't understand it"_ which is how I read it first.

Comment: I had a look at the code and could not see anything wrong. I've tested it on my system and it ran as expected. 'I don't get it' means: I see nothing wrong here, it must be something different. And that difference is that what you have mentioned in your first comment to my answer (but already deleted it).

Comment: As you said, it looks like it's [a bug in VS](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/3212), pure and simple.

Comment: The OP should note that the link you posted has a solution at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools, but it may be easier to ignore the message and trust the compiler.

Comment: @Clifford i would concur. Especially if we are talking about 'an (modified) editor' ;)

Answer (score 0):

The clue is in the error message - you are not *assigning* you are *initialising*.

Change to :

```
struct s a ;
a = array_of_s[0];
```

That said I have never seen an error message like that (with `C/C++(144)` on the end - they are two different languages - that makes little sense).  Moreover it compiles fine in GCC - what compiler (and version) are you using?  Is this in fact not a compiler diagnostic but a pre-parse performed by your IDE/Editor?

Comment: I have to apologize, i missunderstood your comment. You were right from the begin. I have no clue, what i have read, my answer to your comment was not (that) fine.

Comment: Looks like that error message "C/C++" is coming from a Microsoft product, and unlike you and me, Microsoft *does* tend to believe that "C/C++" is one language.  And per the discussion linked to from @ErdalKüçük's answer, it looks like this *is* a pre-parse being performed by an IDE, and a buggy one at that.

Comment: @SteveSummit Like Clifford mentioned in a comment to my answer above, there exists a workaround for that specific error message.